# How to Convert a Javascript Var Holding Html Into a String?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
        var originalHtmlString = '<p>Some text</p>'

        //Create an html object called myHtml that I can work with like w/ document
        var myHtml = document.createElement( 'html' );

        //Make the html object hold the html I wrote in a string so I can edit it as html
        myHtml.innerHTML = originalHtmlString;

        var stringifiedHtml = ???
```

How do I turn the "myHtml" var back into a string after working with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be as easy as

```
var stringifiedHtml = myHtml.outerHTML;
```

[Element.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

Comment: Thanks, I will come back to accept, sorry for dumb question.

Comment: @VSO That wasn't a dumb question, it never occurred to me that was even  possible.

Comment: @zer00ne Good to hear, there's so much stuff out there in terms of html selectors and things like this that most people (at least that I know) dont ever use, especially when heavily depending on angular. Thanks again ade.

Comment: You're welcome, the question was fine, and when you know about `outerHTML` it just seems obvious that it does the opposite of `innerHTML`, but it's not something that is used very often, and lots of people apparently doesn't even know it exists and have been supported for decades.

Comment: Does `outerHTML` really do the "opposite" of `innerHTML` though? From what was given in OP's question, doing `var stringifiedHtml = myHtml.innerHTML` would have been an equally good answer.. the difference between them is whether the element itself is included or not in the returned string. Both properties can be written or read.

Comment: @ChrisMiddleton - Maybe "opposite" wasn't the right word, but they both do what the name implies they do, one gets the HTML inside the given element, the other gets the HTML "outside" the given element, i.e. including the element itself, which is what the OP seems to want, as he already has the original string that was set as the inner HTML.